# upload file to a folder in gcs bucket using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a gcs bucket where there are multiple folders. I need to upload a file that is in my local to a particular folder in the GCS bucket. I am using the below code where it only uploads in the bucket directly but not in a folder of that bucket.

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_to_bucket(destination_blob_name, path_to_file, bucket_name):
    """ Upload data to a bucket"""
     
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account.json')


    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_file)
    
    return blob.public_url

print(upload_to_bucket('hello_world.py', 'hello_world.py', 'gcs_bucket_name'))
```

Folder structure:

```
gcs_bucket_name
     folder_1
     folder_2
```

Can anyone tell me how to upload into a folder of GCS bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GCS there is no something as “folders” since it is a flat namespace. What you see is only an illusion and actually a “folder” is part of the object name.

I'd suggest to read the [documentation for this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders)

Said this you must append the “path” to the `destination_blob_name`.

Then the function could be something like this where the default path is the root of the bucket.

```
def upload_to_bucket(destination_path="", destination_blob_name, path_to_file, bucket_name):
    """ Upload data to a bucket"""
     
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account.json')


    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_path+destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_file)
    
    return blob.public_url
```

And when you call it to upload a file to `folder_2` it could be:

```
upload_to_bucket('folder_2/', 'hello_world.py', 'hello_world.py', 'gcs_bucket_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really folders in GCS. Your "folder" is just a name that gets prefixed to your file name. so `blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)` should be `blob = bucket.blob(folder_name + destination_blob_name)`